# XML xpath on SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I need your help to get from a XML below the list of all (complete) path from root to leaf.

```
<List>
    <V ID="1">
        <F>
            <N>10</N>
            <M>10</M>
            <A>
                <IDX>19</IDX>
            </A>
        </F>
        <F>
            <N>20</N>
            <M>20</M>
            <A>
                <IDX>21</IDX>
            </A>
        </F>
    </V>
    <V ID="2">
        <F>
            <N>100</N>
            <M>100</M>
            <A>
                <IDX>50</IDX>
            </A>
        </F>
        <F>
            <N>21</N>
            <M>120</M>
            <A>
                <IDX>33</IDX>
            </A>
        </F>
    </V>
    <V ID="3">
        <F>
            <N>200</N>
            <M>300</M>
            <A>
                <IDX>99</IDX>
            </A>
        </F>
        <F>
            <N>44</N>
            <M>55</M>
            <A>
                <IDX>64</IDX>
            </A>
        </F>
    </V>
</List>
```

I would like similar:

```
<V ID="1"><F><N>10</N><M>10</M><A><IDX>19</IDX>
<V ID="1"><F><N>20</N><M>20</M><A><IDX>21</IDX>
<V ID="2"><F><N>100</N><M>100</M><A><IDX>50</IDX>
<V ID="2"><F><N>21</N><M>120</M><A><IDX>33</IDX>
<V ID="3"><F><N>200</N><M>300</M><A><IDX>99</IDX>
<V ID="3"><F><N>44</N><M>55</M><A><IDX>64</IDX>
```

Using the follow PHP code I didn't get what I need, where I wrong? can someone sugget something?

```
$test1 = new SimpleXMLElement($testq);

foreach ($test1->xpath('//V') as $value) {
    echo $value["ID"]." - ";

    foreach ($test1->xpath('//V[@ID="'.$value["ID"].'"]/F') as $valueF) {

        echo $valueF->N." - ";
        echo $valueF->M." - ";

        foreach ($test1->xpath('//V[@ID="'.$value["ID"].'"]/F/A') as $valueA) {

            echo $valueA->IDX." - <BR>";        

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot
Ale

Comment: Maybe I don't get it, but: Why don't you just use a RegExp?

Comment: I would like to investigate the possibility that we have with XML xpath navigation... my desiderata is to get the follow lists                                 
1 - 10  - 10  - 19   
1 - 20  - 20  - 21    
2 - 100 - 100 - 50    
2 - 21  - 120 - 33    
3 - 200 - 300 - 99    
3 - 44  - 55  - 64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should simplify you current Xpath expressions. The slash at the start of the expression makes them use the document itself as the context, not the current node. You can reduce them the just the tag name:

```
$test1 = new SimpleXMLElement($testq);

foreach ($test1->xpath('V') as $valueV) {
    echo $valueV["ID"]." - ";

    foreach ($valueV->xpath('F') as $valueF) {

        echo $valueF->N." - ";
        echo $valueF->M." - ";

        foreach ($valueF->xpath('A') as $valueA) {

            echo $valueA->IDX." - <BR>";        

        }
    }
}
```

This uses some Xpath defaults. The long form of an expression like 'V' is 'child::V'. `child` being the the axis. Here are other axes and two are interesting in your case: `descendant` (short `//`) and `ancestor`.

So first lets iterate over all `A` nodes in the document.

```
foreach ($test1->xpath('.//A') as $valueA) {
   echo $valueA->IDX." - <BR>";         
}
```

Now for each of these nodes you fetch the ancestors, iterate them and output data depending on the node.

```
foreach ($test1->xpath('.//A') as $valueA) {
  foreach ($valueA->xpath('ancestor::*') as $ancestor) {
    // change that to handle the different ancestor nodes
    echo $ancestor->getName(), ' - ';
  }
  echo $valueA->IDX, "\n";
}
```